# Translating NSConstraints From Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I'm looking to turn my objective-c based universal application into a Swift project.  I've been able to swap most of the code so far, but I'm having trouble translating the following:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:0
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   relatedBy:0
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
```

I also have to change this code as well:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}
```

Is there a method similar to this in Swift?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance to all who reply. :)

Comment: Try to look into frameworks like Masonry, adding constraints manually is really a chore

Comment: Out of curiosity... why did I lose two reputation by asking this question?

Comment: People tend to down vote questions where they think the person asking the question has not put enough effort in researching the question first. Probably because this is pretty easy to find using Google? https://www.google.com.ar/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swift+constraints+programmatically&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=N5klVc_yJ6jX8gfWwICgAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AutoLayout [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) is generally considered preferrable:

```
var viewsDictionary = [ "contentView" : self.contentView, 
                        "view"        : self.view ]

var viewsConstraint = 
       NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithViaualFormat(
                     "[contentView][view]", 
                      options: 0, 
                      metrics: nil, 
                        views: viewsDictionary)
view.addConstraint(viewsConstraint)
```

---

But you can use the other form as well:

```
var leftConstraint = 
      NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView,
                    attribute: .Leading, 
                    relatedBy: .Equal, 
                       toItem: view, 
                    attribute: .Left, 
                   multiplier: 1.0,
                     constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(leftConstraint)

var rightConstraint = 
      NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, 
                    attribute: .Trailing,
                    relatedBy: .Equal, 
                       toItem: view, 
                    attribute: .Right, 
                   multiplier: 1.0, 
                     constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(rightConstraint)

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I prefer the second version of writing the code.  : )

Comment: @iProgramIt The 2nd way is all I've done in my own code so far, but Apple and other developers on Stack Overflow who have done a lot of their auto layout programmatically say VFL is the way to go, so I'm learning it.

Comment: `Cartography` and `Snap` definitely help you to write less code compared to `VFL`, also you can easily made mistake when you write the VFL code in string, and VFL doesnt take advantage of code autocompletion from XCode.

Comment: @ztan, I will check those out. And sometimes you might want to change `constant` and `multiplier` algorithmically and I'm not sure how one would go about doing that cleanly and easily with VFL yet, but nothing stops one from using a mix even in one source file.  More to learn...  But VFL can summarily represent complex constructs with a lot less code and make it a lot easier to read and tweak. That's life. It's all about the right tradeoffs at the right time.

Comment: @ztan, [Cartography](http://darrarski.pl/2015/01/cartography-swift-auto-layout-helper/) looks pretty handy!

Answer (score 6):

```
 let leftConstranint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

 self.view.addConstraint(leftConstranint)

 let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

 self.view.addConstraint(rightConstraint)
```

`.Leading`, `.Left`, `.Trailing` and `.Right` are Enums from `NSLayoutAttribute`.
Also the function from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
      return false
}
```

With [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography), you can do the above Autolayout in the following:

```
layout(self.contentView, self.view) { (contentView, view) -> () in
        contentView.leading == view.left
        contentView.trailing == view.right
 }
```

With [Snap](https://github.com/Masonry/Snap), you can do the above Autolayout in the following:

```
 self.contentView.snp_makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.leading.equalTo(self.view.snp_left)
        maker.trailing.equalTo(self.view.snp_right)
 }
```

`Cartography` is more a **mathematical way** to make your constraints in code. In other way, `Snap` is more like an **English language way** to describe your constraints in words.

Unlike Visual Language Format (coding your constraints in plain string), both `Cartography` and `Snap` can take advantage of code-completion in XCode.

Comment: @iProgramIt, you can also try some third party library to do the autolayout constraint programmatically, for example, `Cartography` and `Snap`. If you found my answer solved your problem, would you mind marking it as accepted?

Comment: I wonder if Apple would consider adapting something like that. Auto Layout helps but it's still a hassle for complicated situations. *Anything* reasonable that helps the developers get a handle on it is worth the investment, IMO.

Comment: @Allaboutthatbase2 they did, it's called Interface Builder (like it or not)

Comment: @DepartamentoB `Masonry` and `Snap` are developed by the same guy, and they pretty much do the same work. But `Snap` is Swift only library.

Comment: @DepartamentoB yeah, I know that's Apple's attempt to deal with layout nightmares with multiple screen sizes and devices and orientation, and I've used it plenty. All I've needed to do so far to tweak a screen here or there if it was a hassle in IB was make an outlet for one constraint and modify the constant based on screen changes and orientation.  But I'm talking about the convenience of Cartography. Where has apple done *that* to help people on the programmatic side? And will they?

Comment: Yeah I already figured it out and edited my reply :) - didn't realize it had a Swift port already! @Allaboutthatbase2 yeah after ten minutes of working with coded constraints I already started creating wrapper methods, I'm used to Objective-C but that was really more verbosity than I could ever take. The third party tools are pretty great, I recommend Masonry all the time but people that start out tend to work with the standard libraries first before using CocoaPods. They will suffer and hate it.